# Enforce a DITA version for DITA Open Toolkit 1.5.2 XSLT stylesheet

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0, docbook, dita

I have a .xsl that transforms xml from docbook to DITA.  A problem that I'm running into, is that the .dita file thats created destroys xrefs. To fix that, I want to try to enforce a dita version during the transform ( I hope thats possible).  So my question is: How do I have the transformed document respect DITA 1.2 when it is being transformed.

The transformation is from the DITA Open Toolkit 1.5.2 using the docbook2dita plugin
Here's the current .xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0" >
<xsl:import href="./xslt/ditabaseOutput.xsl"/>
<xsl:import href="./xslt/dbReader.xsl"/>

<xsl:output
    method="xml"
    indent="yes"
    omit-xml-declaration="no"
    standalone="no"
    doctype-public="-//OASIS//DTD DITA Composite//EN"
/>
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="." mode="topic.topic.in"/> 
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an example how to perform schema validation of the result of the XSLT 2.0 transformation.

Comment: Besides Dimitre's answer about validating result documents, I think this needs clarification: a transformation is a function from input to output. To output one type of result (say DITA 1.1) or another, depends on how the function is defined. If the function itself doesn't provide a way to specify that (by parameter), then you have to modify the function definition (by extension, composition, etc.)

Comment: @Alejandro: Yes your hitting on exactly what I'm trying todo.  I'm trying to use the DITA OT plugin docbook2dita.  It was written several years ago,i.e. before DITA 1.2. and in the TODO part it says "upgrade to DITA 1.1 and DocBook 5".  What should i look for to upgrade to dita 1.2?

Comment: @Alejandro: Could you, please, clarify?

Comment: @Dimitre: @Ace is asking for a method to use a "DocBook to DITA 1" stylesheet like if it was a "DocBook to DITA 1.2" stylesheet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**XSLT 2.0 is ideal for validating the result of the transformation to a specific XML Schema**. DTD validation isn't supported.

So, if you find an XML Schema for DITA (and there seems to be **[some DITA schema](http://wiki.astrogrid.org/pub/Astrogrid/DarwinInformationTypingArchitecture/DITA-readme.html)** existing), you can validate it easily.
Here is an example, taken from Michael Kay's book "XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0", how to perform validation of the result-document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="iso-8859-1"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
      xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
      xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<xsl:import-schema namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
   schema-location="http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd"/>
<xsl:output method="xhtml" indent="yes"/>                   
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:result-document validation="strict">
    <html>
      <head>
        <title><xsl:value-of select="poem/title"/></title>
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1 align="center"><xsl:value-of select="poem/title"/></h1>
        <p align="center"><i>by </i><xsl:value-of select="poem/author/name"/> 
          (<xsl:value-of select="poem/author/(birth,death)" separator="-"/>)</p>
        <xsl:for-each select="poem/stanza">
          <p>
            <xsl:for-each select="line">
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              <xsl:if test="position() != last()"><br/></xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
          </p>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:result-document>
</xsl:template>                   
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<poem xmlns="http://poetry.org/ns" 
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://poetry.org/ns poem.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <author>
     <name>Rupert Brooke</name>
     <birth>1887-08-03</birth>
     <death>1915-04-23</death>
   </author>
   <date>1912</date>
   <title>The Hill</title>
   <stanza>
      <line>Breathless, we flung us on the windy hill,</line>
      <line>Laughed in the sun, and kissed the lovely grass.</line>
      <line>You said "Through glory and ecstasy we pass;</line>
      <line>Wind, sun, and earth remain, and birds sing still,</line>
      <line>When we are old, are old...." "And when we die</line>
      <line>All's over that is ours; and life burns on</line>
      <line>Through other lovers, other lips" said I,</line>
      <line>"Heart of my heart, our heaven is now, is won!"</line>
   </stanza>
   <stanza>
      <line>We are Earth's best, that learnt her lesson here.</line>
      <line>Life is our cry. We have kept the faith!" we said;</line>
      <line>"We shall go down with unreluctant tread</line>
      <line>Rose-crowned into the darkness!".... Proud we were,</line>
      <line>And laughed, that had such brave true things to say.</line>
      <line>-- And then you suddenly cried, and turned away.</line>
  </stanza>
</poem>
```

the Saxon EE 9.2.1.2 processor produces the following error messages:

```
SystemID: C:\Books\XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0\Downloads\Chapter4\ch04\poem-to-xhtml.xsl
Engine name: Saxon-EE 9.2.1.2
Severity: error
Description: Failed to compile stylesheet. 1 error detected.

SystemID: C:\Books\XSLT 2.0 and XPath 2.0\Downloads\Chapter4\ch04\poem-to-xhtml.xsl
Engine name: Saxon-EE 9.2.1.2
Severity: fatal
Description: Attribute align is not permitted in the content model of the complex type of element h1
Start location: 16:0
URL: http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#err-XTTE1510
```

**Here is a summary how to achieve XML Schema validation** of the result document:

.1. Import at least one schema, for example:

```
<xsl:import-schema namespace="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
   schema-location="http://www.w3.org/2002/08/xhtml/xhtml1-strict.xsd"/>
```

.2. On the `<xsl:result-document>` element specify strict validation, like this:

```
  <xsl:result-document validation="strict">
```

Comment: @Dimititre I agree with the importance of xslt validation, although I'm not quite sure that schemas are the way to solve my problem, since the .XSLTs im looking at don't seem to contain and schema imports.  The comments to the question should help clarify what i mean.

Comment: @Ace: Of course, you must import your schemas -- how otherwise would you verify? It is natural that "the .XSLTs im looking at don't seem to contain and schema imports" -- it is *you* who must insert the `<xsl:import-schema>` directive into the xslt code.

Comment: @Ace: It is simply unwise to ask such a question and not to use the natural schema-validation abilities built into XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @Dimitre: The issue here is that docbook2dita converts to dita 1.0, I need it to convert to dita 1.2, where should I look to change this?

Comment: @Ace: Oh, I see -- sorry, but you phrased your question very misleadingly. You need to know what all differences b/n dita 1.0 and dita 1.2 are and you need to know docbook vwry well. Then, you need to test docbook2dita very extensively and find all possible discrepancies. Finally, you must try to fix these. I think this is probably quite challenging task, depending on the nature and number of differences b/n dita 1.0 and dita 1.2

Comment: @Dimitre: yes I believe that would be quite a task.  What if I only needed a single tag to enforced (in this case <xref>) is there a simple way to preserve that tag?

Comment: @Ace: I think that the only way is to trace the stylesheet with a debugger, to find how your node is process/skiped and add your own rule or modify existing ones.